# Mostrar 5 ultimos datos de varias tablas (MSSQL)

Tags: c#, wpf, mssql

Gente, buenas tardes.
Estoy trabajando con MSSQL y C#
Les comento, necesito hacer una consulta a la base de datos en la que necesito que sean a varias tablas, lo que necesito es que me devuelva los 5 últimos datos de cada tabla que fueron ingresados.

Adjunto foto de las tablas en la bbdd:

[image: BBDD]

El codigo que hice fue este:

```
 private void Boton_HIstoricos(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string Consulta2 = "SELECT TOP 5 CONCAT(IDCaudalBBA,'   ', Escalamin, '   ' , EscalaMax, '   ' , Tiempo) AS Historial FROM CaudalBBA Order by IDCaudalBBA desc "; //Devuelve la informacion que se encuentra en la tabla CaudalBBA
        SqlDataAdapter MiAdaptadorSQL = new SqlDataAdapter(Consulta2, Conexion);
        using (MiAdaptadorSQL)
        {
            DataTable CaudalBBA = new DataTable(); //Lo que se carga en el DataTable es el codigo 'Consulta2'
            MiAdaptadorSQL.Fill(CaudalBBA);
            Consulta.DisplayMemberPath = "Historial"; //Refleja en el TextBox los parametros de la BBDD introducidos en 'Historial'
            Consulta.ItemsSource = CaudalBBA.DefaultView; //Declarando a 'CaudalBBA' como origen de datos
        }
    }
```

El resultado de ese código me da esto:

[image: Resultado]

Perdon, esas lineas "verticales" las puse para que se entienda que cada columna corresponde a cada tabla. También necesito corregir eso.

Creo que se puede ver que los datos que fueron consultados no están ordenados.
¿Como puedo hacer para que al hacer la consulta, me devuelva los 5 ultimos datos ingresados de forma ordenada? Es decir, con ordenado me refiero a que sea la fila numero 7, luego la fila numero 6, y asi hasta llegar al 3.

Perdon si fui muy engorroso para dar a entender, Si no se entiende, voy a buscar de aclararlo mejor. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu **consulta SQL** podría ser esta:

```
select top 5 concat(T.IDCaudalBBA, '   ', T.Escalamin, '   ', T.EscalaMax, '   ', T.Tiempo) as Historial
from (select
        row_number() over(order by (select 0)) as Fila,        
        IDCaudalBBA,
        Escalamin,
        EscalaMax,
        Tiempo
      from CaudalBBA) T
order by T.Fila desc;
```

Lo que se hace aquí es primero la **subconsulta**:

```
select
  row_number() over(order by (select 0)) as Fila,        
  IDCaudalBBA,
  Escalamin,
  EscalaMax,
  Tiempo
from CaudalBBA
```

Donde de la **tabla CaudalBBA** se seleccionan los campos deseados y además se proyecta un nuevo campo llamado **Fila**, el enumera las filas de la tabla.

Sobre esta **subconsulta** se hace entonces una consulta más general, la cual se va a ordenar descendentemente por el **campo Fila** y sería entonces cuando se devolverán los 5 registros deseados.

**Nota:** Solo te muestro la consulta, te toca a ti usarla desde **C#**.

Comment: Muchas gracias Japv!!!!

Comment: @Mauro, si la respuesta dada resolvio tu problema te agradeceria q la marcaras como aceptada, gracias